# Allow customers add embed code to pleers

Tags: php

I have a dating site project and I need to provide to customers possibility to upload embed code with pleer from 3rd part services like:

https://soundcloud.com/

http://joxi.ru/EA4zBRLsDloDzm

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/239151794&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

http://pleer.com/

http://joxi.ru/L21zEK6s6kR8RA

```
<object width="578" height="31"><param name="movie" value="http://embed.pleer.com/small/track?id=B2nq55Bgri8xfBumq&t=grey"></param><embed src="http://embed.pleer.com/small/track?id=B2nq55Bgri8xfBumq&t=grey" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="578" height="31"></embed></object><br> <small><a href="http://pleer.com/tracks/44662018SBp" target="_blank">Cкачать Linkin Park - Numb бесплатно</a> на pleer.com</small>
```

e.t.c.

So any customer should be able to add embed pleer code from any(or most) 3rd part sound services. Now question - how can I create it secure way?

Or maybe someone can provide solution with validation for most popular services?
So customer fill some code and I need some way to validate is it real sound and is this code protected from injections.

Thanks!

Comment: I would limit the services they can use to embed things from. Then using REGEX, extract what you need (for example the ID) from the URL they want to embed. You can then do all of the coding side of things

Comment: IMO the most secure way would be to hist their code on an entirely different domain and just embed pages from that domain, which in turn embed whatever they want.